# Logical array slicing into sub-arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, slice

I want to ask you if someone of you has an idea on how to slice a logical array into sub-arrays in Python. As an example if I have the following array [111 00 10 11] I want to slice into [111],[1],[11] discarding the zeros.

2- how to get also the original indices of ones associated with the sliced sub-arrays,i.e, idx1 = [0,1,2] idx2 =[5] idx3 =[7,8]

Thank you in advance.
Fethi

Answer (score 0):

```
[int(x) for x in '[111 00 10 11]'.strip('][]').replace('0','').split(' ') if x!='']
```

This should help you out

Comment: Yes this is what I m looking for. Just an additional question, how to get also the original  indices of ones  associated with the sliced sub-arrays,i.e, idx1 = [0,1,2] idx2 =[5] idx3 =[7,8]

Comment: This can be done in 2 steps: [x for x,y in enumerate('[111 00 10 11]'.strip('][').replace(' ','')) if y=='1'].....this will give you index of all 1's. Now using the length of groups of 1's extracted,  pop out those number of elements from the above list. Like if 1st group is '111', pop out initial 3 indexes. i.e [0,1,2]. Next when number is '1', pop one elements

Answer (score 0):

With loop or list comprehension:

**Loop**

```
x = [111, 00, 10, 11]

result = []

for i in x:
    if i:
        result.append([i])

print(result)
```

**List comprehension**

```
x = [111, 00, 10, 11]

result = []

result = [[i] for i in x if i]

print(result)
```